# Are there any SQL Validators that can check syntax against multiple database servers?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, validation

Are there any SQL Validators that can check syntax against multiple database servers?

For example, I might want to check whether a particular query will work against Oracle, MySQL and SQL Server.

I am more concerned about the SQL syntax than the actual schema being queried, so a tool that can catch major syntax errors, like detecting that the `limit` clause is not supported in SQL Server and Oracle would be good enough.

---

**EDIT:**

Several answers have suggested checking syntax for a particular DBMS or for ANSI Standard.

What I am looking for a possibility of targeting a sort of union of features between two or more databases (say SQL Server and Oracle). I would like to be able to use any SQL feature that is supported by all of the DBMS I am targeting in a particular application.

I am not sure if it is worthwhile. I think it depends upon the number of non-ANSI features shared by several databases. If there are very few, then perhaps it will be better to target the ANSI standard.

Comment: Maybe the SQLite shell could help. However LEFT and FULL joins are not implemented, and unlike Oracle, you can SELECT from nothing whereas in Oracle you must use DUAL.

Comment: how many databases are you writing for? Or is this an attempt at writing some db agnostic middleware?  Maybe try dbms_sql.parse for Oracle, something similar(?) for other dbms.

Comment: Which versions of each database should it validate too.

Comment: @tbone and everyone else, please see updated question for some clarification.

Comment: @KevinBurton, I am currently looking if there are tools that do thing like this, specific versions of DBMS are not a huge issue at this stage.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015613/online-sql-syntax-checker-conforming-to-multiple-databases

Comment: There are some capabilities in the SQL standard that are not supported by any of the popular databases.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not aware of any that are that specific, these will check that the statements are valid ansi 92/99/2003...

http://developer.mimer.com/validator/index.htm

That will get you 99% of the way there (especially if are only doing CRUD operations)

maybe if you know which reserved words are used by which database you could roll your own simple checker.. 
see : [How to find if a column name is a reserved keyword across various databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7058193/how-to-find-if-a-column-name-is-a-reserved-keyword-across-various-databases/7058247#7058247)

(as already mentioned) If your goal is to create a database agnostic system think about using a third party tool e.g: entityspaces

Comment: I lost bunch of time on one simple syntax error, I didn't close parenthesis (round brackets) in declaration of stored procedure. This link helped me out... [http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/)

Answer (score 2):

For the MySQL: try [automatic SQL syntax check](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/sql-coding.html) feature in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

For the Oracle: PL/SQL Editor in [dbForge Studio for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/oracle/studio/overview.html)

Comment: You have to build Mac versions of your apps :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an online mysql syntax checker, but this is mysql only
http://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.db-fiddle.com/. It supports the following DBs

- MySQL 8.0
- MySQL 5.7
- MySQL 5.6
- MySQL 5.5
- PostgreSQL 13
- PostgreSQL 12
- PostgreSQL 11
- PostgreSQL 10.0
- PostgreSQL 9.6
- PostgreSQL 9.5
- PostgreSQL 9.4
- SQLite 3.30
- SQLite 3.26